# How to get a numerical value from an Android EditText

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext

I want to build a simple android app that computes the area of a triangle.  I have two textView widgets, one editText, and a button.  When the button is pressed, it pass a radius value to a function that calculates it.  I added a variable and initialized it to 5.0 just for testing purposes, however I want to refer to the value put in the editText field as the radius.

Here is my code.
    package com.circle;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.*;
import android.view.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
private Button button1;
public EditText editText1;
public TextView textView1, textView2;
double radius = 5.0, area, perimeter;
public double calculateRadius(double radi)
{ 
    area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
    return area;
}
public double calculatePerimeter(double rad)
{
    perimeter = 2.0 * Math.PI * radius;
    return perimeter;
}   
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);       
    this.button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    this.editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    this.textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    this.textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    this.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View target) 
        {       
            calculateRadius(radius);   //what's wrong?
            calculatePerimeter(radius);  //what's wrong??
            textView1.setText("" + area);  //what's wrong
            textView2.setText("" + perimeter);  //what's wrong?
        }
    });

}
}
```

Comment: A triangle doesn't have a radius.

Comment: Did i say triangle?  I feel stupid now!  LOL, I meant circle.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is casting the radius. Do the following:

1. In the XML file change edit text -input type=number i.e., it takes only numbers..
2. While on click -type cast the radius to double by Double.parseDouble(entered value).
3. In the XML file set txt initial value to 0, to avoid type cast problems  as it cannot typecast null value.

That's all.

Answer (score 2):

```
 private double getRadius(){

        double radiusValue = 0;
        try{
            radiusValue= Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString());
            catch (NumberFormatException e){
                // this is not a number. tell the user something here or do something
                Log.e("yourAppTag", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            return radiusValue;
        }
```

You need to call this everywhere where you have otherwise typed radius.

Also your calculatePerimiter and calcualteArea methods are not using the passsed in parameters. So get rid of the class variable radius, and pass in the radius using the method I have here into your two calculations.

Comment: Oops, did I say triangle?  I feel stupid now.  I meant circle!

Comment: I should be able to just add the line  radius = Double.parseDouble(editText1.getText().toString()); right above the onClickListener without having to create another function right?  It compiles just fine, the problem is when I run it, it crashes when I press the calculate button.  Since (in this code) radius is initialized, it ignores whatever is put in the value for the radius, yet it still crashes when I press the calculate button.  Not I removed the code from the onClickListener method (so it was just blank) to see if it would crash, and it didn't.

Comment: no you can't just add that line above the click listener. That line is reading the input from the edit box. So if you put it where you want to, it would be called before anyone had entered anything... It is likely crashing because you didn't do any error checking to make sure it is actually a double value, and since you called it before anyone entered anything, it's trying to convert blank text to a number. I edited the code to show you